# Disable Spectre and Meltdown mitigations

Tags: performance, vulnerability

Can I disable Spectre and Meltdown mitigation features in Ubuntu 18.04LTS?

I want to test how much more performance I gain when I disable these two features in Linux, and if the performance is big, to make it permanently.

Comment: maybe you have to recompile kernel

Comment: [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Security#Simultaneous_multithreading_(hyper-threading)) provides information about how to secure your system too

Comment: How much performance did you gain?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

A number of kernel boot parameters are available to disable or fine-tune hardware vulnerability mitigations:

- [for Spectre v1 and v2](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/hw-vuln/spectre.html#spectre-mitigation-control-command-line): `nospectre_v1` (x86, PowerPC), `nospectre_v2` (x86, PowerPC, S/390, ARM64), `spectre_v2_user=off` (x86)
- for SSB: `spec_store_bypass_disable=off` (x86, PowerPC), `ssbd=force-off` (ARM64)
- [for L1TF](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/hw-vuln/l1tf.html#mitigation-control-command-line): `l1tf=off` (x86)
- [for MDS](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/hw-vuln/mds.html#mds-mitigation-control-command-line): `mds=off` (x86)
- [for TAA](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/hw-vuln/tsx_async_abort.html#taa-mitigation-control-command-line): `tsx_async_abort=off`
- [for iTLB multihit](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/hw-vuln/multihit.html#mitigation-control-on-the-kernel-command-line-and-kvm-module-parameter): `kvm.nx_huge_pages=off`
- [for SRBDS](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/hw-vuln/special-register-buffer-data-sampling.html#mitigation-control-on-the-kernel-command-line): `srbds=off`
- for retbleed: `retbleed=off`
- [KPTI](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/x86/pti.html) can be disabled with `nopti` (x86, PowerPC) or `kpti=0` (ARM64)

A meta-parameter, `mitigations`, was introduced [in 5.2](https://kernelnewbies.org/Linux_5.2#More_CPU_bug_protection.2C_and_.22mitigations.22_boot_option) and back-ported to 5.1.2, 5.0.16, and 4.19.43 (and perhaps others). It can be used to control all mitigations, on all architectures, as follows:

- `mitigations=off` will disable all optional CPU mitigations;
- `mitigations=auto` (the default setting) will mitigate all known CPU vulnerabilities, but leave SMT enabled (if it is already);
- `mitigations=auto,nosmt` will mitigate all known CPU vulnerabilities and disable SMT if appropriate.

Some of these can be toggled at runtime; see the linked documentation for details.

Comment: Does specifying mitigations=auto,nosmt make linux more secure on CPU without hyperthreading?

Comment: @VladimirKunschikov no, if there’s no SMT to start with then `nosmt` doesn’t change anything.

Answer (score 26):

With a kernel 5.1.13 or newer :

On boot parameter you can use

```
mitigations=off
```

With a kernel older than 5.1.13 :

```
noibrs noibpb nopti nospectre_v2 nospectre_v1 l1tf=off nospec_store_bypass_disable no_stf_barrier mds=off mitigations=off
```

Add either `mitigations=off` or that long one-liner to your `/etc/sysconfig/grub` and re-generate grub's configuration file with

```
grub2-mkconfig
```

(your distributions procedure will vary).

**Debian/Ubuntu derived distributions:**

Edit the file `/etc/default/grub` then run

```
update-grub
```

Comment: I notice you have `mitigations=off` in that long one-liner. Is that going to do anything on older kernels?

Comment: But Ubuntu 18.04 has kernel version 4.15.

Comment: In CentOS 7 and probably all Red Hat distros, you should use `sudo grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg` to properly update and apply these grub changes properly.

Answer (score 4):

On Fedora 37, with a sufficiently new kernel, mitigations status can be displayed by printing the content of files under `/sys/devices/system/cpu/vulnerabilities/`.

```
$ grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/vulnerabilities/*
/sys/devices/system/cpu/vulnerabilities/itlb_multihit:KVM: Mitigation: VMX disabled
/sys/devices/system/cpu/vulnerabilities/l1tf:Not affected
/sys/devices/system/cpu/vulnerabilities/mds:Not affected
/sys/devices/system/cpu/vulnerabilities/meltdown:Not affected
/sys/devices/system/cpu/vulnerabilities/mmio_stale_data:Mitigation: Clear CPU buffers; SMT vulnerable
/sys/devices/system/cpu/vulnerabilities/retbleed:Mitigation: Enhanced IBRS
/sys/devices/system/cpu/vulnerabilities/spec_store_bypass:Mitigation: Speculative Store Bypass disabled via prctl
/sys/devices/system/cpu/vulnerabilities/spectre_v1:Mitigation: usercopy/swapgs barriers and __user pointer sanitization
/sys/devices/system/cpu/vulnerabilities/spectre_v2:Mitigation: Enhanced IBRS, IBPB: conditional, RSB filling, PBRSB-eIBRS: SW sequence
/sys/devices/system/cpu/vulnerabilities/srbds:Mitigation: Microcode
/sys/devices/system/cpu/vulnerabilities/tsx_async_abort:Not affected
```

To disable the mitigations in one swoop, do

```
sudo grubby --update-kernel=ALL --args="mitigations=off"
```

and behold how the printout changed after a reboot

```
$ grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/vulnerabilities/*
/sys/devices/system/cpu/vulnerabilities/itlb_multihit:KVM: Mitigation: VMX disabled
/sys/devices/system/cpu/vulnerabilities/l1tf:Not affected
/sys/devices/system/cpu/vulnerabilities/mds:Not affected
/sys/devices/system/cpu/vulnerabilities/meltdown:Not affected
/sys/devices/system/cpu/vulnerabilities/mmio_stale_data:Vulnerable
/sys/devices/system/cpu/vulnerabilities/retbleed:Vulnerable
/sys/devices/system/cpu/vulnerabilities/spec_store_bypass:Vulnerable
/sys/devices/system/cpu/vulnerabilities/spectre_v1:Vulnerable: __user pointer sanitization and usercopy barriers only; no swapgs barriers
/sys/devices/system/cpu/vulnerabilities/spectre_v2:Vulnerable, IBPB: disabled, STIBP: disabled, PBRSB-eIBRS: Vulnerable
/sys/devices/system/cpu/vulnerabilities/srbds:Vulnerable
/sys/devices/system/cpu/vulnerabilities/tsx_async_abort:Not affected
```

### Beware: Spectre proof-of-concept exploits can run in browser JavaScript

As [the leaky.page proof-of-concept](https://www.zdnet.com/article/google-this-spectre-proof-of-concept-shows-how-dangerous-these-attacks-can-be/) demonstrates, this vulnerability can be exploited from browser JavaScript code. Therefore, as long as you use a web browser, there is value in keeping the mitigations on.

Comment: `lscpu` also shows the list of vulnerabilities and mitigations